# Migrating from a physical database to a cloud database

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

What are the implications of moving a physical database created in Microsoft SQL server 2008R2, that makes use of advanced features like Full-Text Search on varchar(MAX) FILESTREAM BLOBS to [SQL Azure](http://www.microsoft.com/windowsazure/)?

What architectural changes are needed? What steps are involved in this transition? SQL Azure Migration Wizzard can't simply be the magic tool that automagicly makes the transition. 
What are the compatibility issues that the migration tool can not fix and should be worked out "manually"?

Comment: Related: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/5887/2660

Answer (score 7):

Moving the data is pretty easy.  If you are using full text search that feature isn't available in SQL Azure yet.  Neither is FILESTREAM.  If you require full text search then Azure isn't for you.